# 2d-Brownian Motion hitting a specific point

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Let $(W_t)_{t\ge 0}$ be a 2-dimensional Brownian motion on some filtered probability space and $x \in \mathbb R^2$. Further define $\tau_x:=\{t >0 \,:\, W_t=x\}$ the hitting time of the singleton $x$.

I know that it holds $$\mathbb P \left(\tau_x < \infty \right)\; = \; 0$$

Yet, I was wondering if there is a rather simple proof of this property? 
Thank you a lot in advance!

Comment: Someone can help me with this?

Comment: In particular, I am searching for a way that does neither involve the Strong Markov Property of the Brownian Motion nor makes use of Itô's formula. Is this possible?